# John the Ripper Custom Rule

Tags: passwords, cracking

I am using [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to crack a copy of the passwd file at my work. I want to alert users that have weak passwords. I happen to know that many accounts have the default password which is different for every user but matches a specific pattern.

Let's say this is the default password format:

```
'[2nd and 3rd characters in username]cc\d\d\l\l'
```

where `c` is a constant (the same in every password), `\d` is a single digit (0-9) and `\l` is a single lowercase letter.

How would I write a custom rule in john.conf that would check all hashes for all combinations that fit this format *before* trying anything else? I've tried to figure it out myself but I can't find any good documentation.

Comment: I don't understand the spam flags :|

Comment: Or the offensive ones flags! I think you'd have better luck on Serverfault.

Comment: if it belonged somewhere else a vote-migrate would have been more appropriate...